# sqlite3, fmdb, build is failed

Tags: sqlite, fmdb

I'm using sqlite3, fmdb glad to know that, but try to use, build upon get errors. I do not know why. Gcc4.2 compilation options are used. (or LLVM GCC4.2). I need a good solution.

Comment: Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 2):

For those of you that might have this problem. Remove fmdb.m from your project and it will compile fine.